# How to retrieve Salesforce Org Feature settings such as Activity Settings

Tags: apex, metadata-api, jsforce

Is there an easy way through APEX (like Schema.describe) to access feature settings in an org?

Specifically we are interested in checking if Feature Settings -> Activity Settings -> Enable Activity Reminders is on or off.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/59), '*Enable Activity Reminders*' is supported using metadata API but not in apex. Use below in your [activities settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm) to enable on/off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ActivitiesSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableActivityReminders>true</enableActivityReminders>
</ActivitiesSettings>
```

[image]